# Python finding new element in list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to find the new word in `liste2`.

```
liste1 = [['euro2016', '99'], ['portugal', '87'], ['ronaldo', '34']]
liste2 = [['euro2016', '90'], ['portugal', '75'], ['ronaldo', '44'], ['nani', '15']]


l1 = len(liste1)
l2 = len(liste2)

for x in range(0,l2):
    for y in range(0,l1):
        if liste2[x][0] not in liste1[y][0]:
            print liste2[x][0]
```

but my code is giving result like that :

> euro2016
>
> euro2016
>
> portugal
>
> portugal
>
> ronaldo
>
> ronaldo
>
> nani
>
> nani
>
> nani

I guess I have to search liste1[all][0] but I dont know how to it.

Comment: What does `new` mean? your question is not clear.

Comment: Do you want the program just to return `nani`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to find the new word in liste2

---

You can use a list comprehension and apply a `filter` that takes only new items in `liste2`:

```
result = [i[0] for i in liste2 if i[0] not in (j[0] for j in liste1)]
#                              ^      filtering is done here       ^
print(result)
# ['nani']
```

Answer (score 1):

check [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

```
[i for i in liste2 if i[0] not in [j[0] for j in liste1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [8]: dict1 = dict(liste1)

In [9]: dict2 = dict(liste2)

In [10]: print(set(dict2.keys()) - set(dict1.keys()))
set(['nani'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a set of the first element in each list item, and then take the difference. It will return the item in liste2 which is not in liste1:

```
l3 = set(map(lambda x:x[0],liste1))
l4 = set(map(lambda x: x[0],liste2))
print list(l4.difference(l3))[0]
```

Output:

```
nani
>>>
```